# Google compute engine cannot select 1 NVIDIA Tesla K80

Tags: gpu, google-compute-engine, preemptive

I am trying to create preemptible VM on Google compute engine. For some reason I cannot select 1 GPU NVIDIA Tesla K80, it is simply grayed out. I can select 1 GPU NVIDIA Tesla P100.

I can select 2 GPU NVIDIA Tesla K80, but then I get error: "Quota 'PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 in region us-central1."

I don't want to increase quota to 2 GPU, since I will have to deposit more money.

Previously, I was able to select 2 GPU NVIDIA Tesla K80 and launch instance successfully, but something changed in last 2 months or so and now it is not working

Comment: Did you try to create it using the gcloud command line or from an incognito browser? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#create-new-gpu-instance In which region you try to create it? Also take a look into the restrictions https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions

Comment: @Thrahir, I used browser (not incognito) to create instance. Region on us-central1. Funny from your link:NVIDIA® Tesla® K80: is not covered by SLA in us-central1. It previously worked fine.